# Putty: ssh root login to server disabled, how i can setup passwordless access to root on server?

Tags: ssh, authentication, sudo, putty, public-key

For added security, we've disabled root login to server via ssh. We have a special ssh account that users need to login as, and then su as root in they require root access.

How can we setup passwordless logins using putty in this situation? I've setup passwordless login to the special ssh account, but we still need a password when we su as root.

If I'm not clear, feel free to ask me to clarify.

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: centos 5 (more char filler)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also change in your sshd configuration file the following line :

```
PermitRootLogin without-password
```

This will allow users to login as root but only using something else than password (kerberos tickets, ssh keys etc...)

Answer (score 1):

Edit /etc/sudoers via the `visudo` command.

Add

```
specialsshaccount       ALL=(ALL)       NOPASSWD: ALL
```

Tip: http://www.sans.org/reading_room/whitepapers/basics/administration-shared-accounts_1271

Comment: I'm not very comfortable with this. This is not what I meant with passwordless login. I was expecting a client certificate based authentication.

Comment: I'm confused now.  Do you have SSH key based authentication working to specialsshaccount?  If so, that's your "certificate based authentication."  Once a user is logged in, how should they get root if it should be "passwordless?"

Comment: I was hoping for putty to be able to intercept an attempt to login as root and use the private key file for authentication.

Comment: nope, putty is out of the picture here once you successfully get a shell on your centos box.  You've disabled root ssh which leaves su/sudo.  Read the link above for a better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Start with adding the special account to the group: 'sudo'

```
%  useradd -G sudo specialsshaccount
```

Your system may already be configured to allow users in this group to sudo w/o password.

If not place this line in your `/etc/sudoers` (via `visudo` command)

```
%sudo ALL=NOPASSWD: ALL
```

**protip**: it's possible to allow only certain commands to execute without password (`man sudoers`)

Comment: your sudoers line needs to start with %